# Android: Prepare the app data file while deployment

Tags: android, qt, cmake, deployment, config

I am developing android app to work with the schedule. The first time you run the program, there should already be a default schedule (it may sound strange, but I'm just making a program for training). I save the schedule in a json file. So, during deployment, I need to copy this file from resources.qrc to AddDataLocation.
I did it at runtime like this:

```
QString appDataDir = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
if (!QFile::exists(appDataDir))
{
    QDir().mkdir(appDataDir);
}

QString configFilepath = appDataDir + QStringLiteral("/timetable.json");
if (!QFile::exists(configFilepath))
{
    QFile::copy(QStringLiteral(":/timetable.json"), configFilepath);
    QFile::setPermissions(configFilepath, QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::WriteOwner | QFileDevice::ReadOwner);
    qInfo() << "config file saved to: " << configFilepath;
}
else
{
    qDebug() << configFilepath << " already exist";
}
```

How can I copy this file exactly during deployment?
Maybe there is some general approach for deploying applications to android?

Note: I use Qt Framework and cmake.